# Call POST method on a RESTful web service on Android

Tags: android

I am new to android development, already sought on the Internet several tutorials, but found no updated ( that does not contain methods or depreciated classes - sdk23 ) saying about how to send POST requests in android. I need to know how the implementation of the call to a method disclosed in a REST service and how to pass the required parameters. Any suggestion?

Comment: The first answer uses deprecated methods (that were good when they were written), the remainder don't.

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en